# How to Set a Attributes based on Condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a attributes based on certain condition. attributes do certain action with there name

```html
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    updateSegmentDetailsHandler(data.title, data.description)
  }
  isLoadingIndicator={btnLoading}
  disabled={!data.title || !data.description || btnLoading}
  btnColor={'primary'}
  data-bs-dismiss='modal' // how to set this attributes based on condition 
  className="btn text-white"
>
  Save changes
</Button>
```

```html
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    updateSegmentDetailsHandler(data.title, data.description)
  }
  isLoadingIndicator={btnLoading}
  disabled={!data.title || !data.description || btnLoading}
  btnColor={'primary'}
  {btnLoading && ...[data-bs-dismiss='modal']} 
  className="btn text-white"
>
  Save changes
</Button>
```

I did something like this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can add the condition like js only
`data-bs-dismiss={btnLoading ? "modal" : null}`
If the `btnLoading` is true then `data-bs-dismiss` attribute will get `modal` value otherwise it will have null as value

```
<Button
              onClick={() =>
                updateSegmentDetailsHandler(data.title, data.description)
              }
              isLoadingIndicator={btnLoading}
              disabled={!data.title || !data.description || btnLoading}
              btnColor={'primary'}
              data-bs-dismiss={btnLoading ? "modal" : null}
              className="btn text-white"
            >
              Save changes
            </Button>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed, and why. Your answer, as is, requires readers to just guess at what's different...

Comment: I did this but its not working

Comment: once i clicked the button it  triggered the name modal so its doing is action

Comment: the attributes getting the value modal without btnloading is true

Comment: ```btnLoading```'s value is boolean or string ?

Comment: its expecting string

Comment: then u can put condition like ```btnLoading == "true" ? "modal" : null```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your code like this solve your problem.

```
data-bs-dismiss={btnLoading ? 'modal' : ''}
```

Comment: what expression is that

Answer (score 0):

You're very close with the idea of `spread`ing the the prop into the Component

```js
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    updateSegmentDetailsHandler(data.title, data.description)
  }
  isLoadingIndicator={btnLoading}
  disabled={!data.title || !data.description || btnLoading}
  btnColor={'primary'}
  {...(!btnLoading && {"data-bs-dismiss": 'modal'})}
  className="btn text-white"
>
  Save changes
</Button>
```

instead of:

```js
{btnLoading && ...[data-bs-dismiss='modal']}
```

try:

```js
{...(btnLoading && {"data-bs-dismiss": 'modal'})}
```

This will optionally create the object which will then be `spread` in. When the condition is not met, React will find `undefined` and the prop will not be added

I believe for custom attributes like `data-bs-dismiss` (rather than something standard like `class` is, which in React is `className`) the attribute should be written "as is" instead of with camalCase (e.g. `style={{ paddingTop: "10px" }}`); <strike>but I must admit I've not tried to use non-standard attributes attributes...</strike>

#### EDIT:

I tested this for both my custom `Button` component and the raw `button` element and both worked fine...
[image: Custom class being added]

This implies a deeper problem with either `title` or `description` being empty strings or the value of `btnLoading` never being `false`. I'd recommend some `console.log`s and uses of `typeof`...
e.g. `console.log("btnLoading", btnLoading, typeof btnLoading);`

On a second look, it also occurred to me that the line should be:

```js
{...(!btnLoading && {"data-bs-dismiss": 'modal'})}
```

meaning that when the button is not loading, the custom prop should be added.

Comment: i think it wont work for custom attributes

Comment: @Monk Could you expand a little more one what `Button` is? Is this a wrapper component around the HTML `button` element? Because when I used the direct `button` component it worked, but it may not work the same based on what has been defined in `Button`

Comment: Yeah its Wrapped Component

Comment: but i extent with HtmlButtonAttributes so it may work right ?

Comment: actually its not working in default button also

Comment: @Monk not necessarily, it could be that you're not passing in the `...rest` of the props from `Button` into `button`

Comment: BtnLoading Just Working Fine the state is Updated Properly but it not only working on custom attributes .. Any other visually community to connect ???

Comment: I have passed ...rest in my custom button component